# When using mongoimport, can you specify that the _id should be a UUID?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am using mongoimport to import a large number of CSV records to MongoDb.  Currently, by default, the _id field is being set to ObjectId, as shown:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5fea8abcda05f098a1ac9857")
```

Is there a parameter that I can pass to the mongoimport command that will cause MongoDb to generate a new UUID instead for each document as it is imported, such as:

```
"_id" : UUID("0ef6bc1d-017d-4c85-9393-2d7832598d03")
```

Otherwise, if it's not possible to assign a UUID to the _id field on import, is there another query I can write to perform this update on the imported collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be not possible to switch to uuid when importing but you can do something like that:

```
mongoimport --db <your_db> --collection tmpCol --drop --type csv --file data.csv --headerline
```

And then:

```
db.tmpCol.find().forEach(function (document) {
  document._id = UUID()
  db.desiredCollection.insert(document)
})
```

Maybe relevant: https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-mongoimport-and-not-use-objectid-in-the--id-fields/23963/2

Comment: Couldn't you also just update `_id`? The back-up, in case of errors, is already the `.csv`

Comment: @Minsky it seems that this operation is not allowed by MongoDb.  Trying to update the _id field causes it to raise the error "Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'"

Comment: @DalhousieDuck interesting, thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could find, `mongoimport` supports UUID with [MongoDB Extended JSON (v2)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson.Binary).

Extended json has [Special rules for parsing $uuid fields](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/extended-json.rst#special-rules-for-parsing-uuid-fields).

According to documentation (and my tests), `"_id" : UUID("0ef6bc1d-017d-4c85-9393-2d7832598d03")` can be written as:

```json
"_id" : { "$uuid": "0ef6bc1d-017d-4c85-9393-2d7832598d03" }
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with CSV (see [Import UUID from CSV using “mongoimport”](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/import-uuid-from-csv-using-mongoimport/11911/3).

A ticket is opened to implement this functionality: [TOOLS-2788](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-2788).

My solution would be to use something like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/), `awk` and `bash` to preprocess the csv files into json files with the UUID field written in the correct format, and then feed them to mongoimport`.